# How to prevent section slide from being counted as a slide in Beamer Frankfurt?

Tags: beamer, counters, slideshow

I am using Beamer with the Frankfurt theme to create a slideshow. I used Frankfurt because I like how it handles the frame numbering - with non-intrusive dots in the upper part of the slide. The displayed slide has its dot filled, the rest are empty circles. I just have one problem: Latex counts my section title slides to the "list" of dots, so that the first slide with content is counted as the second dot, not the first. I want to change that so that the section slide does not count as a slide for the section, while preserving the entire system. I have researched a bit and found that Beamer is supposed to have at least two ways to achieve that, but none work for me.

What I have tried:

- redefining `AtBeginSection` to include `[noframeumbering]`
- redefining `AtBeginSection` to include `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`, either before the `\begin{frame}` or within it
- putting `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` either before or after the `\section` call or within the first frame after the `\section` call
- putting `[noframenumbering]` in the first frame after the `\section` call
- putting `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` before or after the `\section` call or within the first frame after the `\section` call

Minimal Working Example below, with all the attempts I have tried in comments.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usetheme{Frankfurt} \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    
    \AtBeginSection[]{ %\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} %\addtocounter{page}{-1}   \begin{frame}[plain]%, noframenumbering]   %\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}   %\addtocounter{page}{-1}   \vfill   \centering   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%   \end{beamercolorbox}   \vfill
    
    
      \end{frame} 
%\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} 
%\addtocounter{page}{-1} }
    
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    
    \title[no title]{There is no title} \author{fake author} \institute{fake institute} \date{01.01.2001}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame}
    
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1} 
%\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    
    \section[section title]{section title}
    
     %\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} 
%\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    
    \begin{frame}%[noframenumbering] 
    %\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} 
    \frametitle{fake title no 1} fake frame no 1 
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame} 
\frametitle{fake title no 2} fake frame no 2 
\end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile